# Что такое Idle при загрузке страницы?

Tags: отладка, frontend

И почему он такой долгий на этой картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Idle** - это простой в ожидании дальнейшего действия.

Comment: А почему он тогда останавливается на 38 сек а не бежит дальше?

Comment: Закончились действия, которые нужно ждать. Вообще, лучше просматривать не такую статистику, а таймлайн.